# Hive SQL Select is not working with multiple AND criteria, showing error: The operator 'AND' accepts at least 2 argument

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to run a very simple query that just select all the rows based upon some multiple criteria and all are inclusive i.e. I am using AND in select HiveQL statement. The table is an external table in Hive and the storage handler is phoenix, so I checked in phoenix also about that query and it is working fine, but in Hive, it is showing some java IO exception error which I am not able to get where I am wrong. The query I am using is:

```
SELECT * FROM msme_api.msme_jk WHERE gender='Male' AND socialcategory='General';
```

The complete error message is:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentLengthException: The operator 'AND' accepts at least 2 argument. (state=,code=0)
```

I am trying for external and for internal Hive tables, In both, the issues are still the same but when I give order by, OR  statement then it's surprising that it works.

```
SELECT * FROM msme_api.msme_jk WHERE gender='Male' AND socialcategory='General' order by aid;
SELECT * FROM msme_api.msme_jk WHERE gender='Male' OR socialcategory='General';
```

Both works fine but with AND, I am getting the error.

I still confused about how hive is taking and processing the above queries and why I am not able to execute simple select statement. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try adding brackets to your conditions?

Comment: Hi @mck like that, "select * from msme_api.msme_jk where (gender='Male') and (socialcategory='General');" But the error is same.

Comment: Hi @mck if you can provide me some more clear information that could really help me.

Comment: are you using hue or shell ? I do not have any comment on this issue because this is strange and shouldnt happen. But i am thinking this may be related to your client.

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy I am using Zeppelin, Beeline both, this issue is coming for both the cases and I can think of it as it may happen with some tables but this issue is coming for every tables. I still not able to know whats the issue.

Comment: is some simple SQL like `select 1 from msme_api.msme_jk where 1=1 and 2=2` ?

Comment: can you try using double quotes? `WHERE gender="Male" AND socialcategory="General" `